# How to find consecutive start/end dates when they aren't in consecutive rows

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I didn't see a question similar to what I need, so I decided to ask. I'm sorry if this is a duplicate.

I have a rather large data frame (> 800k rows) that looks like below and I want to create a data frame of all rows where the Start Date is the same day or the very next day as one of the previous End Dates for each ID and Group combo.

```
ID    Group    Start    End     V1
1     A        14688    14689   127
1     A        14690    14699   131
1     A        14690    14692   26
1     B        14690    14694   73
1     B        14694    14696   145
1     B        14695    14696   57
1     B        14670    14675   223
```

As you can see, there are multiple rows with the same Start Date or with the same End Date, which I can't seem get around with using the `shift()` function in the `data.table` package. I have tried the following, but this only looks at the previous row and not above that as well. I'm not sure how to go about looking above just the previous row (2 above, 3 above, ..., 20 above, etc). The above  table is called "input."

```
df.1 <- input[input$Start - shift(input$End, type = "lag") <= 1 & input$Start - shift(input$End, type = "lag") >= 0, ]
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the Start and End dates are numeric. It's something weird I've come across. I think they're the total number of days of that ID at that point in time.

Comment: What's your expected output look like for the example above?

Comment: My expected output is just a data frame with all of the columns of the data where; 1) the Start Date equals an End Date of another row, or the Start Date -1 equals an End Date of another Row. I need both rows in the output, though (ex: the row where the Start date equals some other End date and the row of the End Date that equals the Start date)

Comment: @GingerOverlord see my potential answer...is my output what you expect?

Comment: @CPak, Yes, your output looks like what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try

#### your data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Group = c("A", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), Start = c(14688L, 14690L, 14690L, 
14690L, 14694L, 14695L, 14670L), End = c(14689L, 14699L, 14692L, 
14694L, 14696L, 14696L, 14675L), V1 = c(127L, 131L, 26L, 73L, 
145L, 57L, 223L)), .Names = c("ID", "Group", "Start", "End", 
"V1"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))
```

#### function

```
myfun <- function(df) {
             pairs <- combn(nrow(df), 2)
             df[unique(c(pairs[, apply(pairs, 2, function(x) diff(c(df$Start[x[2]], df$End[x[1]])) <= 1)])), ]
         }
```

#### explanation of function

I use `combn` to figure out which `End` dates and `Start` dates to compare.

```
             [,1] [,2] [,3]
End     [1,]    1    1    2
Start   [2,]    2    3    3
```

This compares End[1] to Start[2], End[1] to Start[3], etc.

I then check the difference between `End-Start` pairs and if `<= 1`, then save those indices. I use `unique(c(...` to obtain only unique row-indices. Return those rows.

#### solution

```
splitdf <- split(df, list(df$ID, df$Group))
library(purrr)
map_df(splitdf, ~myfun(.x))
```

#### output

```
  ID Group Start   End  V1
1  1     A 14688 14689 127
2  1     A 14690 14699 131
3  1     A 14690 14692  26
4  1     B 14690 14694  73
5  1     B 14694 14696 145
6  1     B 14695 14696  57
```

#### with additional check for single-observation groups

You could try

```
map_df(splitdf, ~if(nrow(.x) >1) { myfun(.x) })
```

Comment: I get an error when I run this in combn() that n < m that I haven't been able to figure out yet.

Comment: You must have groups with only a single observation. Try something like my update (at the bottom).